# Cumulative sum in R with condition on multiple columns

Tags: r, sum, conditional-statements

My dataset contains Subscription cancellations by months since establishment till today and months that the subscription was active before it got cancelled:

```
 Country_of_Ownership__c CiWF_Payment_Method__c Months_since_Established Months_before_Cancellation count
 1:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                       10                          3     1
 2:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                       27                          9     1
 3:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                       25                          6     1
 4:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                       24                          6     1
 5:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                       31                          2     1
 6:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                       21                          4     1
 7:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                       23                          1     1
 8:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                       24                          5     1
 9:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                       50                          0     1
10:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                       12                          1     1
11:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                       13                          9     1
12:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                       16                          2     1
13:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                       21                          8     1
14:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                       13                          0     1
15:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                       14                          8     1
16:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                       48                          9     1
17:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                       37                          8     1
18:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                       37                          0     1
19:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                       11                          6     1
20:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                       12                          3     1
21:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                        4                          1     1
22:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                        3                          1     1
23:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                        7                          7     1
24:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                        6                          4     1
25:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                        6                          2     1
26:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                       15                          3     1
27:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                        5                          2     1
28:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                       10                          1     1
29:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                        3                          0     1
```

I would like to get to the below - the number of cancellations that were cancelled before n-th month (Months_before_Cancellation<n) among those that were possible to cancel in the n-th month (Months_since_Established>=n).

```
    Country_of_Ownership__c  CiWF_Payment_Method__c max_Months_before_Cancellation count
 1:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                        1     4
 2:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                        2     9
 3:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                        3     13
 4:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                        4     14
 5:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                        5     15
 6:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                        6     15
 7:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                        7     16
 8:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                        8     16
 9:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                        9     19
10:                      NL      Credit/Debit Card                        10    22
```

This can be obtained by running below for each n=1..10
`sum(grouped_reg_atr[Country_of_Ownership__c=="NL" & CiWF_Payment_Method__c=="Credit/Debit Card" & Months_before_Cancellation<n & Months_since_Established>=n,count])`

However, the full dataset has higher n, different countries and payment methods, so I need more automated method - could anybody help please?

Comment: Hello! To clarify, you'd like to find the cumulative sum for each individual group? In this case, `dplyr`s `group_by` function seems like a good bet. If this is what you want, let me know and I'll make a full answer, including a [reprex](https://www.tidyverse.org/help/)

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I think this is a bit more complicated than simple cumulative sum. I noticed before the code that I was using didn't display correctly, fixed now.

Comment: It's possible `hutilscpp::cumsum_reset`will be useful.